Upgrade of a freshly installed WSL1 Ubuntu 24.04 fails
I have freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04 in WSL1, then I wanted to upgrade the Ubuntu system using apt full-upgrade.
During the upgrade I got the following errors:
Setting up systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.4) ...
Initializing machine ID from random generator.
Failed to take /etc/passwd lock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Then I got many subsequent errors because systemd is not configured:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-sysv:
 systemd-sysv depends on systemd (= 255.4-1ubuntu8.4); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.
 systemd-sysv depends on systemd; however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-sysv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

The upgrade process ended with the following errors:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 netplan.io
 dbus-user-session
 systemd-timesyncd
 udev
 systemd-hwe-hwdb
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 netplan-generator
 systemd-resolved
 snapd
 systemd-sysv
 cloud-init
 ubuntu-minimal
 ubuntu-wsl
 libnss-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

How to solve this problem?
The problem seems to be reproducible for a new Ubuntu 24.04 installations of WSL1 instances.
Hint: This problem does not seem to occur in a WSL2 instance.

WSL1 has never and cannot support systemd only WSl2 supports it. WSL1 is dead.  Why are you using WSL1? Ubuntu 24.04 was never intended to be used with WSl1.

I think it's less a matter of Ubuntu 24.04 than of systemd. I have seen that older Ubuntu versions (18.04, 20.04, 22.04) which I have used with WSL1 do not use systemd. Is there an Ubuntu 24.04 without systemd? I do not need systemd.

(18.04, 20.04, 22.04) were all released while WSL1 was still supported.  WSL for a while has only really support WSL2 especially since it's transition to Windows Store.

After some time of research and testing, I didn't find a direct solution, but I did find two workarounds:
Apparently the problem occurs during the upgrade of systemd. Triggered by the post-install script, a file lock is attempted which is not supported or not handled correctly by WSL1, whereupon this error occurs and the installation cannot be completed cleanly.
This error seems to be fixed in WSL2 and maybe never in WSL1. A workaround in systemd was rejected by Poettering.
Workaround 1: pin systemd
Easily possible as long as no upgrade has been attempted and the problem has not yet occurred.

Prevent the upgrade of systemd by pinning the package using hold in apt.
apt-mark hold systemd
apt-mark hold systemd-dev

Then upgrade the system normally:
apt update && apt full-upgrade


Workaround 2: override command
Possible if the error has already occurred and the installation is to be completed.
The error occurs in the post-install script of systemd (/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst), more precisely when calling the command systemd-sysusers in this script.
You can link the binary systemd-sysusers to echo, for example. This allows the post-install script to be executed, except for the command that is executed via systemd-sysusers, as this only generates an output via echo, but you no longer run into an error.

cd /bin && mv -f systemd-sysusers{,.org} && ln -s echo systemd-sysusers && cd -
apt install -f

Source of the 1st command: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10397#issuecomment-1780132430
Hint: I am not sure about the future effects or problems by "disabling" the systemd-sysusers command.
